# how to get values in pandas dataframe which is equivalen with LIKE Operator in SQL?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

can i get specific column value in dataframe like the SQL like operator that can find any values then count the value to store it in the new column. here is the code for my dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

dataku = pd.DataFrame()

dataku['CIF'] = ['789', '290', '789', '789','290']
dataku['NAMA'] = ['de','ra','de','de','ra']
dataku['SALDO'] = [100,500,800,200,500]
dataku ['PRODUK']=['tabungan','deposito','deposito','tabungan','deposito usd']

dataku.groupby(['CIF','NAMA','PRODUK']).agg({'SALDO':'sum', 'PRODUK':'count'}).rename(columns={'SALDO':'TOTAL SALDO','PRODUK':'TOTAL PRODUK'})
```

the result i want for the new dataframe is like this

```
CIF NAMA PRODUK   TOTAL_SALDO  TOTAL_PRODUK  GT_SALDO  GT_PRODUK
290  ra  deposito         500             1      1000         2
         deposito usd     500             1                      
789  de  tabungan         300             2       300         2
         deposito         800             1       800         1
```

how i can get the value of GT_SALDO column and GT_PRODUK like the table above as the final result?

Answer (score 0):

I am not enturely sure this is what you want, but you can groupby on parts of the strings stored in a column. For example, this is your original groupby, stored in `df1`

```
df1 = dataku.groupby(['CIF','NAMA','PRODUK']).agg({'SALDO':'sum', 'PRODUK':'count'}).rename(columns={'SALDO':'TOTAL SALDO','PRODUK':'TOTAL PRODUK'})
```

This is a groupby that only uses first 8 characters of the `'PRODUK'` column:

```
df2 = dataku.groupby(['CIF','NAMA',dataku['PRODUK'].str.slice(stop=8)]).agg({'SALDO':'sum', 'PRODUK':'count'}).rename(columns={'SALDO':'GT_SALDO','PRODUK':'GT_PRODUK'})
```

`df2` looks like this

```
                    GT_SALDO    GT_PRODUK
CIF NAMA    PRODUK      
290 ra  deposito    1000       2
789 de  deposito    800        1
        tabungan    300        2
```

You can join the two to get something that looks like your desired output:

```
df1.join(df2)
```

produces

```
                        TOTAL SALDO TOTAL PRODUK    GT_SALDO    GT_PRODUK
CIF NAMA    PRODUK              
290 ra  deposito        500         1               1000.0      2.0
        deposito usd    500         1               NaN         NaN
789 de  deposito        800         1               800.0       1.0
        tabungan        300         2               300.0       2.0
```

you can `fillna` NaNs if they bother you